# Generating legacy WSDL C++ MFC .NET 2.0 from Java 8 WSDL

Tags: java, soap, jboss, wsdl, wildfly

Recently, our Java product has migrated from Java 1.6_45 to Java 1.8_202. This product is based on web methods and wsdl generation which now is done by the following libraries (v. 2.3.2) during ant build phase:

- jaxws-rt
- jaxws-tools
- policy
- streambuffer
- jaxb-xjc
- jaxb-jxc
- jaxb-impl
- jaxb-osgi

Now, I need to convert a pair of all these WSDL in a format valid for legacy .NET 2.0, as there are some components developed in C++ which run under IIS and which are integrated with our product. These legacy components are developed with Vsiual Studio 2005 with .NET framework 2.0 and ASP-NET 2.0.
Previously, this was done by using a JBoss 5.1.0 and copying the jar of our product into the /bin directoty.
Then, this command was launched:

```
jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin>wsprovide -o wsdl -c product.jar -w java_classpath_to_web_service
```

But now, both Jboss 5 and Jboss 7 cannot work with Java 8 built jars, so is there a way to get these old format WSDL? Maybe some special parameter to pass to wsprovide executable. Essentially they are without .schema files, which are eclosed into the WSDL itself and some few other peculiarities. 
The "issue" is about Visual Studio 2005 which wants the WSDL in a specific old format, otherwise it cannot import them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin that you can use during build to produce your wsdl, or once the app is deployed, just add ?wsdl onto the url for your webservice to download

Comment: Thank you for your reply but what I need to be done is an old style WSDL generation (without schema files and some other differences). If I use Maven plugin during build, I may get a different (current) wsdl definition than the one I really need

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the WSDL spec itself has never really changed. Do you have a copy of the old wsdl to compare? Key different types of WSDL are RPC style and Document-Literal

Comment: Sorry for the late, yes I have the copies. How shall I enclose them?

Comment: Post to pastebin.com and add link here maybe